# NDSolve post-processing: Calculate the flow over a FEM-boundary

Tags: finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I'm trying to calculate the heat loss from buried pipes with NDSolve`FEM. For this I set Dirichlet conditions at the model top and bottom and temperature dependant Neumann conditions at the contact surface between the fluid inside the pipes and the pipe. The solution looks reasonable, but I have trouble **calculating the flow resulting from the Neumann conditions**. The steady state solution looks like this:

[image]

Here's what I've done: 
This is the geometry, mesh and coefficients:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=46720655068131319221

```
{boundaryMeshs, bmesh, mesh, κTensor, steadyState} = 
  Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "problemData.mx"];
```

I started by assembling the boundary mesh from multiple boundary meshs. E.g. boundaryMeshs[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsOXf.png)] being the right contact area fluid-pipe, which is the one of interest. The κTensor includes the thermal diffusivity of each component and has the unit [m^2/s].

```
op = Inactive[ Div][-κTensor.Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]

ΓDirichlet = {
 DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 10, ElementMarker == 9], 
 DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 10, ElementMarker == 11]
 };

ΓNeumann = NeumannValue[(55 - T[x, y]) 25, ElementMarker == 1] + 
       NeumannValue[(30 - T[x, y]) 25, ElementMarker == 5];
```

ElementMarker==1 corresponds to the mentioned area and the flow is defined by the fluid temperature, the pipe temperature and the heat transmisson coefficient which is calculated by the Nusselt number, but considereed to be 25 for simplification here.

```
steadyState = NDSolveValue[{op == ΓNeumann, ΓDirichlet}, T, {x, y} ∈ mesh]
```

Now I want to calculate the actual resulting flow, preferably by using my mesh. For this I picked the  boundary mesh corresponding to this contact area and use the same equation as for the Neumann condition.

```
NIntegrate[(55 - steadyState[x, y]) 25, {x, y} ∈ boundaryMeshs[[1]]]
Out= 0.0000292133
```

The result would be 0.03 mW/m_pipe if I am interpreting this right. This doesn't seem right. Earlier I had the same caluclation resulting in 0  a lot of times. I guess my Integral is over the area of boundaryMeshs[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsOXf.png)], which is a RegionHole and not over its surface. I just can't figure out how to do this right. I guess there's a very easy/elegant way. If somebody has an idea and could help me, I would be very grateful. I would expect the result to be of the magnitude 2-20 W/m.

ADDITION:
If I calculate the same for the left pipe I get an even smaller number:

```
NIntegrate[(30 - steadyState[x, y]) 25, {x, y} \[Element] 
  boundaryMeshs[[5]]]
Out: 1.19173*10^-6
```

I calcluated the flow for the right pipe by defining my integration limits "by hand" and get a result in the range I expect, but it would be much more efficient for me to use the boundary markers, since I want to change the geometry.

```
NIntegrate[(55 - 
    steadyState[0.06625 Sin[\[Alpha]] + 0.25, 
     0.06625 Cos[\[Alpha]] - 1]) 25, {\[Alpha], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

Out: 6.11905
```

In this approach 0.06625 is the radius and {0.25,-1} the center of the pipe.

Comment: Count the flow on the second pipe.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. The second pipe should be considered as well.

Comment: Calculate the integral around the second pipe.

Comment: I updatet my question

Comment: You use the interpolation function as a solution, so the integral should be described exactly.

Comment: I am not sure if i can trust my solution with the approach of calculating the Neumann condition. If I use this, the temperature T [x,y] has to be the one exactly at the contact surface.

Comment: You made a mistake when calculating the heat flux across the pipe boundary. The result must be multiplied by the radius of the pipe. What are the units of input data?

Comment: I updatet my question with the information. Are you sure about the radius and where exactly? I guess it's covered by the limits of the integration.

Comment: In the polar coordinates that you use the surface element $ds=rd\alpha $

Comment: To calculate the heat flux, it is necessary to multiply the boundary condition by a dimensional factor or temperature gradient multiplied by the thermal conductivity  $\vec q=-k\nabla T$ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85668/discussion-between-jufo-and-alex-trounev).